# Best Practices for improving Software Quality

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs

We are looking for methods to improve our internal processes when developing software.

We have already adopted TDD contiguous integration and Agile. Any obscure features of visual studio or TFS?

All suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there can be a magic bullet. Beauty (or in this case quality) is in the eye of the beholder.

With that said, I can give you some suggestions as to some of the ways we ensure code quality.

One suggestion can be to include Code Coverage into your assessment of Software Quality. It is one thing to have unittests written for your code, but code coverage helps you identify what code is actually 'covered' by a test, which can sometimes identify use-cases/scenarios that you may not have considered. I recommend you investigate [nCover](http://www.ncover.com/).

You may also wish to dig deeper and look into using [nDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)...

> NDepend is a tool that simplifies
>   managing a complex .NET code base.
>   Architects and developers can analyze
>   code structure, specify design rules,
>   plan massive refactoring, do effective
>   code reviews and master evolution by
>   comparing different versions of the
>   code.

I appreciate that these are not TFS features but you can easily 'integrate' them into your visual studio environment using [TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/)

This is of course not an exhaustive list of things - you need to find what suits you and gives you the confidence about your code's quality.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thats a good point how do we know if we are improving if we are not messuring quality.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a helpful list: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html ("The Joel Test: 12 Steps to Better Code" by Joel Spolsky)

Comment: My apologies for the general answer, I thought TFS meant something different - since I don't do much in the Microsoft world I didn't realize it meant Team Foundation Server. Hopefully the link will be helpful anyway, if you hadn't already seen it.

Comment: This is Great "Hallway usability testing" is a good Idea Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't have anything to do, and you have the resources you can try **code review**. This procedure includes double checking the code before every (real) commit. This helps to catch bugs early in the development process. Google is using this technique widely.

Sadly the tools supporting these kind of procedures are pretty basic and hard to use currently. If you do a googling on you'll find one or two simple code review tool for TFS.

Be careful though. These techniques doesn't help you make good software alone. You still need a good architecture, quality code, etc. (Okay, TDD helps code quality, but architecture is still a gray area.) I'm not aware of any techniques that help that currently and doesn't hurt the development process too much. You have to wait till Visual Studio 2010 comes out with all the bling-bling of model validation, automatic uml diagram generation, etc.

Comment: Hmm TFS code review tools, at the moment we print the code. Perhaps the tools can save a few tree's :).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I believe in [code reviews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review). Some of advantages are:

- Constantly keeping an eye on code quality and coding standards.
- It's **easy to notice** any **unusual/buggy/hard** to understand coding structures (i.e. long `if` conditions, strange type conversions, etc.).
- While **reading someone else code** it's easier **to notice all false assumptions** (could be negative false) (i.e. this object is never `null`), which could introduce bugs.
- It **makes familiar** with **all changes to source code**, so it's easy to remember that this piece of code was lastly modified (which could introduce bugs).
- It makes **easy to learn** (and teach) **good habits**.

And I **do not believe** in any tools, which are thread as special kind of [silver bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet) -- which is not true.

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz, we are already doing code reviews and they are a great help.

Answer (score 1):

read: [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556154844)

Comment: It's a good book. And what are your best tips from code complete?

Comment: My tip from Code Complete (two years later, I realize) - simply understanding A)That there are multiple measures of software quality which may or may not be orthogonal, and B) knowing what they are and which ones you care most about.

Answer (score 1):

It is good that you have implemented TDD, CI and Agile.  Just having ANY process is far better than many places I have seen.  Code reviews are probably the single best way to disseminate knowledge and flesh out defects early.

For my money, though, stick to the basics.  If you are not doing requirements management, you should consider it.  You should know what your customer requirements are when you start your sprint or development cycle. Conduct a review of those and discover your derived requirements, if any. Lastly, you should come up with a way to verify that 1) you built everything you intended 2) you tested everything the customer asked for.  There are processes to do this but if you can find a way that's good for you, do it!

RM takes less time than code reviews and catches the "really big" mistakes.

Comment: Hmm, This is intresting. I think this is an area were we could improve. And tips on were to start?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably the most happiest guys if you have already adopted TDD, CI and Agile and have nothing to do =) I think you have a very big field of process improvement with TDD and Agile practices.

Comment: We are going in the the right direction. But always room to improve.

Comment: What else could we look at. Are you doing somthing new with agile or TDD?